# How to display multiple entries from an HTML form?

Tags: html, perl, functional-programming, cgi

I have a Perl CGI script. I'm trying to display the user entries on every line but it's not working. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI qw( :standard);

print header;
my %hash = (
             'Tyrone'   => 1,
             'Sue'      => 1,
             'Marshall' => 1,
             'Hiroshi'  => 1,
             'Jose'     => 1,
          )


print start_html(
    -title => 'Students in Class'
);

# Process an HTTP request
my $rollcall = param("names");
my @students_in_class = split(/;/, $rollcall);

foreach my $student (@students_in_class){
   if (exists $hash{$student}) {
       print h1('One student is '. $student . '<br>');
   } else {
       print h1('That student was sick today'. '<br>');
     }
}
```

Such that if the user enters the following into the search bar: `Tyrone;Tommy;Marhshall`

the CGI should produces the following output

## Desired Output

One student is Tyrone

That student was sick today

One student is Marshall

---

For some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work at all? Try `perl -c yourperl.cgi`

Comment: syntax error at studentsInclass.cgi line 15, near ")


print"
studentsInclass.cgi had compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing semicolon after hash definition,

```
my %hash = (
         'Tyrone'   => 1,
         'Sue'      => 1,
         'Marshall' => 1,
         'Hiroshi'  => 1,
         'Jose'     => 1,
      );
```

Comment: thanks. Somewhat advanced question but I made a nooby syntax error.